# Swift passing structs between view controllers?

Tags: struct, swift

My app has the user log into their account. Then, the app accesses Parse.com to retrieve all of their information. That information is stored in a struct. I want to have that struct passed between view controllers so it can be accessed at any time in the app. Everything I've tried gives me errors. I can't declare it as an optional, or set up an identical struct in the next class. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Wrap it in a class? Why do you insist on using a struct?

Comment: You should be able to pass structs (or classes) around between view controllers without a problem. Show the code where your doing the pass and tell us what errors or uninstended behaviour your are getting when that code runs.

Comment: how to wrap it in a class? var body and some view very confusing

Answer (score 7):

Use the following code to pass struct between ViewControllers

```
    //FirstViewController.swift

    struct GlobalStruct
    {
    var details:String;
    init()
    {
        details = "global struct";
    }
    };

    class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }
@IBAction func buttonClicked()
    {
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondview") as SecondViewController
        var passData = GlobalStruct();
        passData.details = "Secret Information :)";
        secondViewController.setStructDataReference(passData); //passStruct
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}


//SecondViewController.swift

class SecondViewController:UIViewController
{
    var structData:GlobalStruct;

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    println("struct data = \(self.structData.details)");
}
func setStructDataReference(structDataReference:GlobalStruct)
{
    self.structData = structDataReference;
}

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        self.structData = GlobalStruct();
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create empty arrays [Struct] on both controllers.
Then in whatever action you perform before `performSegue` you should do:

self.arrayinmaincontroller.insert(the struct, at:0)

and pass it in `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`